# The shape of line differs fom information coming from linear regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

The line which represents linear regression (Using the `scikit-learn` library) is totally different from the information that you can get from the library, e.g. LR.intercept_ and LR.coef_. As an example, I have the figure below:
[image]

But the information coming from the attributes of the library are below:
[image]

I don't know which one should be trusted?
Of course, the attributes are designed to reach the goals like this but I feel I got confused.

Comment: Did you look at where x = 0 and the what x would be at like 0.05 with that slope? It looks correct to me.

Comment: This looks broadly consistent. You have y very close to 0.0 at x=0.000, and looks like about y=0.7 at x=0.050, giving a slope close to 14, which seems very close to the values you got. Perhaps you could describe what you expect to see?